# Loading gif on Listview while its populating

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I am trying to add a loading gif on a listview while its populating. I have one listview in which we select a category which then creates a new listview in which all the data comes through an ajax call & i am using select2 for multiple option select, but when i select the data it takes a lot of time to populate the list at that time the page becomes unresponsive while its loading.

So i want the user to to know that its loading the data so he has to wait. So i need your help for some examples for listview.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let more = document.querySelector("button");
let show = document.querySelector(".show");
let loading = document.querySelector(".loading");


more.addEventListener("click",function(){
 
 loading.classList.add("show");

  let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      let back = xhttp.response;
      back = JSON.parse(back);
      let imgSrc = back.results[0].picture.large;
      
      let imgEl = document.createElement("img");
      imgEl.src = imgSrc;
      show.appendChild(imgEl);
   loading.classList.remove("show");
      
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://randomuser.me/api/", true);
  xhttp.send();

});
```

```css
img{
  
  display: inline;
  
}

.more{
  
  position: fixed;
  top: 1em;
  right: 5em;
  background: skyblue;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.loading{
 width: 10em;
 height: 10em;
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
 top: 5em;
 right: 1em;
 background: #212323;
 padding: 0.5em;
}

.loading.show{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300/?random" />
<div class="show"></div>
<button class="more">More</button>
<img src="http://www.lettersmarket.com/uploads/lettersmarket/blog/loaders/common_metal/ajax_loader_metal_512.gif"class="loading">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really appreciate it. can you modify the code so that it doesn't  uses a button to display the gif rather when you user selects an option on listview it automatically starts while its populating the new listview

Comment: Do you mean when the user is scroll almost bottom of the page,then it will ajax the request?

Comment: i mean when the listview is initially loading to show the user that the data is loading rather then when user is scrolling through the data